# Application utilizing two serial ports (native RS485 + USB RS232) receives delayed responses

Tags: c#, windows, serial-port, rs485

I am working with a legacy application (MSVC19, C# with .NET 4.5.2 on Windows 10) which serves as Front-end to an uninteresting appliance. To facilitate the communication to the appliance, two serial connections are established. A serial RS485 (115200 baud 8N1) to the MCU board and an usb FTDI RS232-to-TTL (9600 baud 8N1) adapter connecting a third-party sensor platform.

The specific issue I am trying to diagnose is that the application is experiencing delayed response times from the sensor platform connected via the USB Serial port shortly after any communication on the *other* serial port happens. Normally, the response times of the sensor platform are consistent between 10 and 100 milliseconds. In the ill-performing set-up the response delay can go up to 20 seconds.

To isolate the issue I have extracted all communication into an minimal application. I also replaced both MCU and Sensor platforms with decoys based on arduino systems to make sure that neither the MCU or sensor platforms can be the cause.

After these precautions I can trigger the issue with my test code by connecting the MCU decoy of the appliance via the native RS485 port. I can prevent the issue by connecting the MCU decoy via an USB RS485 transceiver. Here are log excerpts that show the issue.

Well performing set-up (USB RS485, USB RS232)

```
[27.11.2019 11:21:19] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:21:19] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00086 z 00083]
[27.11.2019 11:21:19] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    15,6 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:21:20] MCU: TX: $;version;*
[27.11.2019 11:21:20] MCU: RX: [$;version;pass;MCU;Proto4;Hw2;*]
[27.11.2019 11:21:20] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    15,6 ms) [$;version;*]
[27.11.2019 11:21:21] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:21:21] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00086 z 00089]
[27.11.2019 11:21:21] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    15,6 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:21:22] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:21:22] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00085 z 00076]
[27.11.2019 11:21:22] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    31,2 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:21:23] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:21:23] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00085 z 00089]
[27.11.2019 11:21:23] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    31,2 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:21:24] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:21:24] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00085 z 00079]
[27.11.2019 11:21:24] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    15,6 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:21:25] MCU: TX: $;temp;*
[27.11.2019 11:21:25] MCU: RX: [$;temp;pass;55;0;0;0;0;0;*]
[27.11.2019 11:21:25] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    15,6 ms) [$;temp;*]
[27.11.2019 11:21:26] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:21:26] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00086 z 00094]
[27.11.2019 11:21:26] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    31,2 ms) [Q]
```

Ill-Performing setup (Native on-board RS485, USB RS232)

```
[27.11.2019 11:19:56] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:19:56] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00088 z 00084]
[27.11.2019 11:19:56] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    15,6 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:19:57] MCU: TX: $;version;*
[27.11.2019 11:19:57] MCU: RX: [$;version;pass;MCU;Proto4;Hw2;*]
[27.11.2019 11:19:57] BaseMessage: Message completed: (     0,0 ms) [$;version;*]
[27.11.2019 11:19:58] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:20:06] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00088 z 00095]
[27.11.2019 11:20:06] BaseMessage: Message completed: (  7997,9 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:20:07] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:20:07] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00088 z 00090]
[27.11.2019 11:20:07] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    31,2 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:20:08] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:20:08] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00089 z 00097]
[27.11.2019 11:20:08] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    15,6 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:20:09] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:20:09] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00089 z 00089]
[27.11.2019 11:20:09] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    31,2 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:20:10] MCU: TX: $;temp;*
[27.11.2019 11:20:10] MCU: RX: [$;temp;pass;55;0;0;0;0;0;*]
[27.11.2019 11:20:10] BaseMessage: Message completed: (     0,0 ms) [$;temp;*]
[27.11.2019 11:20:11] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:20:16] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00089 z 00091]
[27.11.2019 11:20:16] BaseMessage: Message completed: (  4967,8 ms) [Q]
[27.11.2019 11:20:17] SENSOR: TX: Q
[27.11.2019 11:20:17] SENSOR: RX: [Z 00089 z 00092]
[27.11.2019 11:20:17] BaseMessage: Message completed: (    15,6 ms) [Q]
```

It is quite obvious that in the ill-performing setup, whenever a message is sent to the MCU platform, the next response of the sensor platform is delayed by several seconds. I have verified by inspecting the output of my arduino decoys that the request message to the sensor platform ("Q") is received without delay, and a response is immediately sent. The delay must therefore happen on the receiving path of the PC or in my application.

I also tried interfacing only the sensor platform from the application and then using a terminal to perform manual communication to the MCU platform. In this case, no delays are occuring.

As this is my first time connecting a RS485 based serial port, is there anything I need to look out for? I've checked if there are any other settings in the Computer's BIOS but except for the protocol (RS232/RS485) and the usual address and interrupt numbers, there isn't anything.

Are there any known bugs with Window's handling of the serial ports ? It is incredibly hard to google this problem because of the prevalence of USB converters. I don't believe the issue is in my code as it works perfectly in the well performing dev-setup.

Sources to the test app are below; If someone is interested I can put up the decoy's sources as well. Unfortunately I had to remove a lot of the comments and log outputs in order to not exceed the post length. If neccessary I can find a different place to upload the snippet.

**Update 1**

I've trimmed the minimal sample to be even more minimal while still exhibiting the behaviour. I have changed the PC BIOS setup in a way that the PC now uses RS232 on all COM ports and used an external RS232<->RS485 bridge to connect the MCU to COM1. Then I connected an RS232<->TTL converter to COM2 and connected the sensor to that. The end result is that there are no more USB converters involved, just plain old on-board COM ports.

I was hoping that having close to the "default" configuration in the BIOS would work well. But it seems not to be the case. Even like this, the delayed response persists.

I also changed the bitrate to consistent 9600 for all connections, to make sure it is not a bitrate conversion issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace MultiSerial
{
    public class MultiSerialTest
    {
        public string TAG { get { return "Test"; } }
        const int ciQueryInterval = 1000;
        LogCollector logger;

        SerialComm mcucomm;
        COMSettings mcuComSettings;
        SerialStreamDecoder mcuDecoder;

        SerialComm Sensorcomm;
        COMSettings SensorComSettings;
        SerialStreamDecoder SensorDecoder;

        ManualResetEvent evtSensorConnected;
        ManualResetEvent evtMCUConnected;

        public void run(string mcu_port, string sensor_port)
        {
            evtSensorConnected = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            evtMCUConnected = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            logger = new LogCollector();
            logger.InitLog("CommTest.log");

            mcuComSettings = new COMSettings(9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            mcuDecoder = new SerialStreamDecoder(
                MCUCommMessage.preamble,
                MCUCommMessage.delimiter,
                MCUCommMessage.terminator
            );
            mcucomm = new SerialComm(
                mcuComSettings,
                mcuDecoder,
                VerifyMCU,
                false,
                logger,
                mcu_port,
                "MCU"
            );

            SensorComSettings = new COMSettings(9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            SensorDecoder = new SerialStreamDecoder(
                SensorCommMessage.preamble,
                SensorCommMessage.delimiter,
                SensorCommMessage.terminator
            );
            Sensorcomm = new SerialComm(
                SensorComSettings,
                SensorDecoder,
                VerifySensor,
                false,
                logger,
                sensor_port,
                "SENSOR"
            );

            Sensorcomm.ConnectDevice();
            mcucomm.ConnectDevice();
            int counter = 0;
            while (true)
            {                
                if (counter == 5)
                {
                    VersionRequest verReq = new VersionRequest(mcucomm);
                    verReq.Send();
                    verReq.AwaitCompletion();
                    counter = 0;
                }
                else
                {

                    FetchRequest fetchReq = new FetchRequest(Sensorcomm);
                    fetchReq.Send();
                    fetchReq.AwaitCompletion();
                }

                counter++;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ciQueryInterval);

            }

        }

        void VerifySensor(SerialComm comm, out bool bSuccess)
        {
            comm.Log(TAG, "Servicing verification request for SensorComm");
            FetchRequest fetchMessage = new FetchRequest(comm);
            fetchMessage.Send();
            fetchMessage.AwaitCompletion();

            if (fetchMessage.result == 0)
            {
                comm.Log(TAG, "Verification for SensorComm successful");
                bSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                comm.Log(TAG, "Verification for SensorComm failed");
                bSuccess = false;
            }
            return;
        }

        void VerifyMCU(SerialComm comm, out bool bSuccess)
        {
            comm.Log(TAG, "Servicing verification request for mcuComm");
            VersionRequest versionMessage = new VersionRequest(comm);
            versionMessage.Send();
            versionMessage.AwaitCompletion();
            if (versionMessage.result == 0)
            {
                comm.Log(TAG, "Verification for mcuComm successful");
                bSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                comm.Log(TAG, "Verification for mcuComm failed");
                bSuccess = false;
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MultiSerialTest test = new MultiSerialTest();
            test.run(args[0], args[1]);
        }
    }

    public class FetchRequest : SensorCommMessage
    {
        new string TAG { get { return "SensorComm:FetchRequest"; } }

        // Request = "Q\r\n"
        // Response = [<identifier><whitespace><value>]^n
        public FetchRequest(SerialComm comm)
            : base(comm,fetch_instruction)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ParseReplyContents(List<string> tokens)
        {
            // Dummy validation
            if (tokens.Count < 2 ||
                 tokens.Count % 2 != 0) { return false; }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public abstract class SensorCommMessage : BaseMessage
    {
        new string TAG { get { return "SensorCommMessage "; } }

        public const char preamble_ch = 'Z';
        public const char delimiter_ch = ' ';

        public static readonly string preamble = preamble_ch.ToString();
        public static readonly char delimiter = delimiter_ch;
        public static readonly string terminator = "\r\n";

        public const string fetch_instruction = "Q";

        private string instructionToken;
        private List<string> userTokens;

        public SensorCommMessage(SerialComm _comm, string _instructionToken) 
            : base(_comm)
        {
            instructionToken = _instructionToken;
        }


        public override string ToWireString()
        {
            string message =
                instructionToken;

            if (userTokens != null)
            {
                foreach (string token in userTokens)
                {
                    message += token;
                    message += delimiter;
                }
            }            
            return message;
        }

        public override bool ParseReplyFrame(List<string> replyTokens)
        {
            bool bHandled = false;            
            bHandled = ParseReplyContents(replyTokens);
            if (bHandled) { MessageCompleted(); }            
            return bHandled;
        }

        protected abstract bool ParseReplyContents(List<string> replyContentTokens);
    }

    public class VersionRequest : MCUCommMessage
    {
        public string DeviceId { get { return strDeviceId; } }
        string strDeviceId;
        public string ProtocolVersion { get { return strProtocollVersion; } }
        string strProtocollVersion;
        public string HardwareVersion { get { return strHardwareVersion; } }
        string strHardwareVersion;


        // Request = $;version;*
        // Response = $;version;pass;DeviceId;ProtocolVersion;HardwareVersion;*
        public VersionRequest(SerialComm comm)
            : base(comm,version_instruction)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ParseReplyContents(List<string> tokens)
        {
            // Expect precisely 3 remaining tokens
            if (tokens.Count != 3)
            {
                return false;
            }
            strDeviceId = tokens[0];
            strProtocollVersion = tokens[1];
            strHardwareVersion = tokens[2];

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class ParseHelper
    {
        public static bool ParseFloatToken(string strToken, float fMin, float fMax, out float fValue)
        {
            fValue = float.NaN;
            if (float.TryParse(strToken, out fValue) &&
                fValue >= fMin &&
                fValue <= fMax)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static bool ParseIntToken(string strToken, int iMin, int iMax, out int iValue)
        {
            iValue = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(strToken, out iValue) &&
                iValue >= iMin &&
                iValue <= iMax)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    public class SerialStreamDecoder
    {
        public string TAG { get { return "SerialStreamDecoder"; } }

        public string preamble;
        public char delimiter;
        public string terminator;

        public SerialStreamDecoder(string _preamble, char _delimiter, string _terminator)
        {
            preamble = _preamble;
            delimiter = _delimiter;
            terminator = _terminator;
        }

        public bool DecodeMessageFromStream(SerialComm comm, out string message, out List<string> tokens)
        {
            string strRx = "";
            message = "";
            tokens = null;
            // Read until terminator     
            strRx = comm.usart.ReadTo(terminator);
            // Re-append terminator because it does not get included in the read
            strRx += terminator;

            // If a preamble is set, scan input sequence for preamble
            int preampleIndex = 0;
            if (    preamble != "" &&
                (   preampleIndex = strRx.IndexOf(preamble)) > 0)
            { 
                strRx = strRx.Substring(preampleIndex, strRx.Length - preampleIndex);
            }
            message = strRx;
            tokens = strRx.Split(delimiter).ToList<string>();

            return true;
        }

    }

    public abstract class MCUCommMessage : BaseMessage
    {
        public string TAG { get { return "MCUCommMessage "; } }

        public const char preamble_ch = '$';
        public const char delimiter_ch = ';';
        public const char terminator_ch = '*';

        public static readonly string preamble = preamble_ch.ToString();
        public static readonly char delimiter = delimiter_ch;
        public static readonly string terminator = terminator_ch.ToString();

        public const string version_instruction = "version";

        public const string okay_result = "pass";
        public const string fail_result = "fail";

        private string instructionToken;
        private List<string> userTokens;

        public MCUCommMessage(SerialComm _comm, string _instructionToken ) 
            : base(_comm)
        {
            instructionToken = _instructionToken;
        }

        public override string ToWireString()
        {
            string message = preamble + delimiter + instructionToken + delimiter;
            if (userTokens != null)
            {
                foreach (string token in userTokens)
                {
                    message += token;
                    message += delimiter;
                }
            }
            message += terminator;
            return message;
        }

        public override bool ParseReplyFrame(List<string> replyTokens)
        {
            bool bHandled = false;            
            string lastToken = replyTokens.ElementAt(replyTokens.Count - 1);
            if (replyTokens.Count < 4 ||
                replyTokens[0] != preamble ||
                replyTokens[1] != instructionToken ||
                lastToken != terminator)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!bHandled &&
                replyTokens[2] == fail_result &&
                replyTokens.Count == 6
            )
            {
                ParseHelper.ParseIntToken(replyTokens[4], int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, out result);
                bHandled = true;
            }

            if (!bHandled &&
                replyTokens[2] == okay_result)
            {
                List<string> payloadTokens = replyTokens.GetRange(3, replyTokens.Count - 4);
                bHandled = ParseReplyContents(payloadTokens);
            }
            if (bHandled)
            {
                MessageCompleted();
            }

            return bHandled;
        }

        protected abstract bool ParseReplyContents(List<string> replyContentTokens);

        public void AddTokens(IEnumerable<string> tokens)
        {
            if (userTokens == null) userTokens = new List<string>();
            foreach (string token in tokens)
            {
                userTokens.Add(token);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseMessage
    {
        public string TAG
        {
            get { return "BaseMessage"; }
        }

        public ManualResetEvent evtMessageRelease;

        public delegate void MessageCompletedEventHandler();
        public event MessageCompletedEventHandler EvtMessageCompleted;

        protected SerialComm comm;

        DateTime timestampRequest;
        DateTime timestampReply;

        public int result;

        public BaseMessage(
            SerialComm _comm
        )
        {
            comm = _comm;
            evtMessageRelease = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public int Send()
        {
            timestampRequest = DateTime.Now;
            comm.TransmitSync(this);
            return result;
        }

        public void AwaitCompletion()
        {
            evtMessageRelease.WaitOne();
        }


        public abstract string ToWireString();

        protected void MessageCompleted()
        {
            timestampReply = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan duration = timestampReply - timestampRequest;
            comm.Log(TAG, "Message completed: (" + string.Format("{0,8:F1} ms", duration.TotalMilliseconds) + ") [" + this.ToWireString() + "]");

            if (EvtMessageCompleted != null)
                EvtMessageCompleted();

            CleanupMessage();
        }

        private void CleanupMessage()
        {
            evtMessageRelease.Set();
        }

        public abstract bool ParseReplyFrame(List<string> tokens);

    }
    public class LogCollector
    {
        StreamWriter streamwriter;

        public void InitLog(string file)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(".\\logs");
            FileStream filestream = new FileStream(".\\logs\\" + file, FileMode.Create);
            streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
            streamwriter.AutoFlush = false;

        }

        public void Log(string tag, string message)
        {
            string logMessage = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] " + tag + ": " + message;
            streamwriter.WriteLine(logMessage);
            streamwriter.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
        }
    }

    public class COMSettings
    {
        public int baudrate;
        public Parity parity;
        public int databits;
        public StopBits stopbits;

        public COMSettings(int _baudrate, Parity _parity, int _databits, StopBits _stopbits)
        {
            baudrate = _baudrate;
            parity = _parity;
            databits = _databits;
            stopbits = _stopbits;
        }

    }

    public class SerialComm
    {

        public string TAG { get { return strTag; } }
        string strTag;

        LogCollector logger;
        public void Log(string tag, string message)
        {
            if (logger != null)
                logger.Log(tag, message);
        }

        COMSettings comSettings;
        public SerialPort usart;

        private string preferredPort;
        private BaseMessage currentMessage = null;
        private SerialStreamDecoder decoder;

        public delegate void VerifyDeviceResponseDelegate(SerialComm comm, out bool bSuccess);
        private event VerifyDeviceResponseDelegate DeviceResponseVerification;

        public delegate void MessageReceivedDelegate();
        public event MessageReceivedDelegate EvtMessageReceived;

        Thread connectThread;

        public SerialComm(
            COMSettings _comSettings,
            SerialStreamDecoder _decoder,
            VerifyDeviceResponseDelegate d,
            bool _bReconnectEnabled,
            LogCollector _logger,
            string _preferredPort,
            string tag = "SerialComm"

        )
        {
            comSettings = _comSettings;
            decoder = _decoder;
            DeviceResponseVerification = d;
            logger = _logger;
            preferredPort = _preferredPort;
            strTag = tag;               
        }


        public bool ConnectDevice()
        {
            bool bDeviceVerified = false;
            try
            {
                usart =
                new SerialPort(
                    preferredPort,
                    comSettings.baudrate,
                    comSettings.parity,
                    comSettings.databits,
                    comSettings.stopbits
                );
                usart.Open();
                usart.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);


                DeviceResponseVerification(this, out bDeviceVerified);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                bDeviceVerified = false;
            }
            if (!bDeviceVerified)
            {
                if (usart != null)
                {
                    usart.Close();
                    usart.DataReceived -= OnDataReceived;
                    usart = null;
                }

            }

            return usart != null;
        }

        /* OnDataReceived
            * Handles received serial communication
            */
        private void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Read until terminator
                if (usart == null) return;
                List<string> tokens = null;
                string message = "";
                if (!decoder.DecodeMessageFromStream(this, out message, out tokens))
                {
                    return;
                }

                Log(TAG, "RX: [" + message.Trim() + "]");
                bool bHandled = false;
                // Check if we received a response to the current message
                if (!bHandled && this.currentMessage != null)
                {
                    bHandled = currentMessage.ParseReplyFrame(tokens);
                }

                if (bHandled)
                {
                    if (EvtMessageReceived != null)
                        EvtMessageReceived();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }


        public void TransmitSync(BaseMessage message)
        {            
            currentMessage = message;                        
            WriteCurrentMessage();
        }


        public void WriteCurrentMessage()
        {
            usart.Write(currentMessage.ToWireString() + "\r\n");
            Log(TAG, "TX: " + currentMessage.ToWireString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Without reading/ understanding the entire code in your question: Could it be that sending a message to the MCU platform blocks the Thread the program is running on?

Comment: I've debugged lost of these type problems.  There answer is no always the same.  first make sure you DO NOT connect the voltage pin from the USB/RS-232 adapter which will connect the PC voltage to the sensor.  Then make sure you use the vendor driver for his USB-RS232 (not the standard microsoft driver).  And make sure you have both the hardware and software handshaking disabled.  Other suggestions 1) Always use As asynchronous 2) Do not close connection keep open forever while application is running.  3) Do not use timers.  Not needed when using asynchronous mode for reads.

Comment: @MindSwipe no, although there is multithreading involved while connecting, at least in my test the message handling is done the main thread and it is strictly synchronous (Message to MCU -> Wait for response -> Message to Sensor -> Wait for response ... )

Comment: @jdweng the sensor is powered solely by the +Vb from the USB and has no other connections. While this is a valid point I believe this not be the cause here. Regarding 1-3) the original application code is using asynchronous transmissions. I'm not the original author and have no idea about the quality of the code, also the application is haunted by sporadic disconnects. I have not yet fully understood what happens, but those delays look pretty suspicious. After those the (original) application is unable to restore the connection on its own unless restarted.

Comment: If the delay is only happening once on startup it is not bad.  It is probably due to alignment of the event and the clock.  In the send while loop (forever) the following line is not really needed : tempReq.AwaitCompletion();  There is a one second delay in the loop and additional delays are not required.

Comment: @jdweng I have left the devices running for about 60 minutes but unfortunately there was not a sign of the delays improving. They happen _every_ time a message is sent though the native RS485 port. Will try without the wait statement, these are just to ensure that the log output is uniform (otherwise the messages are interleaved and the log is hard to interpret). Thanks for the advice so far!

Comment: @jdweng Thinking about it, maybe the naming of the awaitCompletion() method is off. The method does not wait for the IO transaction to be completed, but in fact, waits for the response to the message to arrive. Which in the real application is critical since a certain value (in this case, temperature) has to be returned, which is only available when the response has been received.

Comment: In my opinion, you have a driver issue. Can you say what board and driver in particular? For some of these boards, you can choose the bus type (RS232, RS422 or RS485) at BIOS level, do you have that choice? If so updating the BIOS or at least looking at the revision notes of the updates might be worthwhile. To make sure it's a hardware, driver or BIOS issue you could use the USB RS485 on the ill-performing rig, right?

Comment: @Marcos G. Just as you say, there is the option to select a procotcol (RS232, RS422/RS485 Full Duplex, RS485 Half duplex) and the Interrupt / Address settings of the ports in the BIOS. Selected is RS485 Half Duplex. The particular model is Spectra PowerBox 110-N4200-R10 - It is rather new (bought in 2019) so I'd guess we have an up-to-date bios. I have used the USB dongle in the ill performing box and it turns the setup into a well performing one. To make things worse, we tried different industrial computers, all with on-board rs485, all to the same result (see above). USB always seems to work

Comment: While there was a newer driver kit on the manufacturer's web site, installing those made no difference.

Comment: even the latest driver is quite old, from 2016... I'm not willing to bet but it really looks like a driver issue. Are you able to switch to RS232 or RS422 and test to see what happens?

Comment: I'm have my doubts about drivers, because we used two completely different PCs (different manufacturers and specs) and both exhibited exactly the same behaviour. Might be the same bios though, have not checked that. My gut feeling agrees with you, though. ... I already tried the RS422/ RS485 Full Duplex setting , but then I was not able to connect to the MCU at all. RS232 is not easily feasible because our MCU platform needs the RS485 signal levels (and we do not have a converter).

Comment: Yes, it can be either BIOS or driver issues... Is that second PC also using the same driver (Intel IO Serial)?

Comment: I will continue to work on this tomorrow. Thank you for your input so far.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome. It might come as a surprise but your problem could also be a hardware issue. I've seen this kind of problem when you mix isolated with non-isolated RS485 transceivers. I could not find any documentation but it's quite likely the Intel UART is isolated as compared to most USB UARTs which are not. If you don't have a thrid GND wire it might be a good exercise to add it and see what happens. There might also be a biasing problem. If you have the time and patience you might want to take a look at [this link](http://support.fccps.cz/download/adv/frr/RS485/RS485.html).

Comment: @Marcos G. --- FYI --- I have edited the question with some updated info (changed the protocols).

Comment: Well, that's kind of disappointing, I was hoping for a hardware issue but if changing to RS232 does not fix it I think it has to be definitely a driver issue. The only other thing that comes to mind is either contacting the supplier or boot with Linux and test the port.